# Select faces with similar uvs?

Tags: uv

I'm working on a voxel game where some meshes use the same repeating uvs. I'm trying to select faces with similar uvs so that I can easily change the tile used for them (e.g. different leaf colors).

[image: voxel tree]

I've seen the "Select Similar" menu, but nothing there seems to work for finding faces with the same uvs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my how-to:

1. In UV/image editor select "keep UV and Edit mode mesh selection in sync"
   and Face select mode:

[image]

2. Now select in 3D view needed face, and you will see it in UV/image editor:

[image]

3. And finally, use <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd> to select all faces in that position:

[image]